# Flutter Dropdown for Widget

Tags: flutter, widget, popup, dropdown

I want to open DropDown on tap with Different Widget in.(**Dialog which open like DropDown**)
To show account details or other option.
I attach sample image what I want to do.

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This looks more like a [Dialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html)

Comment: Yeah. I want dialog which is open as dropdown. Like open with aligned object.

Answer (score 0):

The package custom_pop_up_menu was exactly what I was looking for.